# Disabling GraphQL introspection requests on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql, graphql-ruby

For company policies reasons I must disable the introspection feature of `graphql-ruby` gem (making the `__schema` requests fail / return 404).

How do I achieve this?

The application is based on Ruby on Rails version 5.2.2 and the `graphql-ruby` gem version is 1.8.12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`graphql-ruby` documentation](http://graphql-ruby.org/schema/introspection.html#introspection-entry-points):

> You can re-implement these fields or create new ones by creating a custom EntryPoints class in your introspection namespace:
>
> ```
> module Introspection
>   class EntryPoints < GraphQL::Introspection::EntryPoints
>     # ...
>   end
> end
> ```

That said, just introduce `def __schema` method redirecting to `404` or explicitly responding with `404`.

---

FWIW, [here is the original code](https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/blob/master/lib/graphql/introspection/entry_points.rb#L10-L15) you are to overwrite.

Answer (score 2):

graphql-ruby (>= 1.9.7) supports disable_introspection_entry_points .

See https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/pull/2327

Answer (score 1):

If someone is looking for a dynamic option, an approach might be to use a custom Analyzer.

1. Pass a context variable such as authorize_introspection when calling your schema:

```
class GraphqlController < ApplicationController

  def execute
    context = context.merge(authorize_introspection: admin?)

    result = MySchema.execute(query, 
      variables: variables, 
      context: context, 
      operation_name: operation_name, 
      root_value: root_value
    )
    render json: result.to_json
  end

 (...)
```

2. Then use it here

```
class QueryAnalyzer < GraphQL::Analysis::AST::Analyzer

  def on_leave_field(_node, _parent, visitor)
    introspection_field_names = %w[__schema __type]
    field_def = visitor.field_definition

    if field_def.introspection? && introspection_field_names.include?(field_def.graphql_name)
      @introspection_present = true
    end

    super
  end

  def result
    return if introspection?

    GraphQL::AnalysisError.new('Not authorized to query schema internals')
  end

  private

  def introspection?
    @introspection_present && introspection_authorized?
  end

  def introspection_authorized?
    ENV['DISABLE_INTROSPECTION_ENTRY_POINTS'] != 'true' && query.context[:authorize_introspection]
  end
end
```

3. Make the declaration on the schema

```
  class MySchema < GraphQL::Schema

    use GraphQL::Analysis::AST
    query_analyzer QueryAnalyzer

    (...)
  end
```

source: https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/issues/1240#issuecomment-393936456